# SQL Server: Convert IPv6 to INTEGER

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have the following IPv6 to Convert into `INT`.

Given: IPv6

```
DECLARE @IPv6 VARCHAR(MAX) = N'2001:200::'
```

Earlier I was converting IPv4 with following query.

```
SELECT  CONVERT(bigint, PARSENAME(Item,1)) + 
        CONVERT(bigint, PARSENAME(Item,2)) * 256 + 
        CONVERT(bigint, PARSENAME(Item,3)) * 65536 + 
        CONVERT(bigint, PARSENAME(Item,4)) * 16777216 AS IPAddressInt,Item
FROM udf_Split(@IPv6,',')
```

I tried same with the IPv6 but getting an following error.

> Error converting data type nvarchar to bigint.

Comment: `PARSENAME` is for extracting server name, database name, schema name and object name from a qualified object. Its expects the separator to be `.` not `:`. Thats the first mistake. Even after you fix it, there will additional problems in parsing the empty `..`. I believe `PARSENAME`  isn't a good fit here.

Comment: @Pரதீப், Yes! That query I was using for IPv4. Any idea for IPv6?

Comment: First mention whats the expected output here.

Comment: @Pரதீப், The expected output will be `4026531839`, Not sure how it has been converted got this value from front end c#.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `COALESCE` to assign zero to an empty IP component.  Also, `PARSENAME` is intended to be used for database objects, whose components are separated by dot, not colon.  So, replace colon with dot here:

```
SELECT
    CONVERT(bigint, COALESCE(PARSENAME(REPLACE(Item, ':', '.'), 1), 0)) + 
    CONVERT(bigint, COALESCE(PARSENAME(REPLACE(Item, ':', '.'), 2), 0)) * 256 + 
    CONVERT(bigint, COALESCE(PARSENAME(REPLACE(Item, ':', '.'), 3), 0)) * 65536 + 
    CONVERT(bigint, COALESCE(PARSENAME(REPLACE(Item, ':', '.'), 4), 0)) * 16777216 AS IPAddressInt,
    Item
FROM udf_Split(@IPv6, ',');
```

Comment: The above given IPv6 is getting 0 in the output after your query, I got the value `4026531839` from front end C# code. I am not sure how they are calculating this value but I am looking for an integer/bigint value.

Comment: Yes, I don't know why.  If all four number components are there, it works.

Answer (score 0):

you will need to convert it from base 16 to base10 and then split and use the formula given here:https://www.ip2location.com/faqs

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34037043)